# Login with Windows Credentials (AD, LDAP, Active Directory) in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, active-directory, ldap

I'm creating an app that one of his needs is to integrate the app with his AD. Basically, the user of the app should login to the app using his credentials that are at the AD Server. After the login, I'd like to call a specific page that responses a JSon, and I'd like to show this JSon to the user in a UITableView. The page that has this JSon has access only with the credentials of the user, by the way, every time that the user needs to get this JSon (that is always updated), he should send his credentials to the server again.

I have a JSon that I'd like to get from a server, but this server requires the user login through Windows Authentication (AD/LDAP).

The JSon string is the following:

```
{"Result": [{"ID":1,"Name":"Mary Anne","Email":"mary@anne.com"},{"ID":2,"Name":"John Cut","Email":"john@cut.com"}]}
```

Thank you!

---

EDIT

That's the method that I tried, but I think that this one is only for Basic Authentication:

```
func printJSonWithAuthentication(url: String, username: String, password: String) {
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let userPasswordString = "\(username):\(password)"
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let options = NSDataBase64EncodingOptions()
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(options)
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    var running = false
    let url = NSURL(string: url)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (let data, let response, let error) in
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("*************")
            print(httpResponse)
            print("*************")
            print(dataString)
            print("*************")
            print(data)
            print("*************")
        }
        running = false
    }

    running = true
    task.resume()

    while running {
        print("waiting...")
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

At the variable dataString I received the following error (resumed):

```
<h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
<h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
```

But I'm pretty sure that the credentials are valid (I can access the URL from the browser with these credentials).

Comment: What is the question ? If you need a guide of how to authenticate your iOS app with AD, have you tried anything to do that, what are your limitations ?

Comment: Hi @A-Live, I'm creating an app that one of his needs is to integrate the app with his AD. Basically, the user of the app should login to the app using his credentials that are at the AD Server. After the login, I'd like to call a specific page that responses a JSon, and I'd like to show this JSon to the user in a UITableView. The page that has this JSon has access only with the credentials of the user, by the way, every time that the user needs to get this JSon (that is always updated), he should send his credentials to the server again.

Comment: It is clear what you want to do, what you need to highlight is where the problem is. I suggest starting from authorization since the rest is quite common: add a clear question, what you tried and why it didn't work in your opinion, what options you can see and which of them you'd like to use or can't use. Otherwise your question looks more like a request to upload a project where you'd only need to insert the URL, that's not how SO works (at least not usually).

Comment: Hum, thanks for the tip @A-Live . I just put the code with more information. Swift is totally new for me (4 months) and didn't needed to ask so many times here in SO before.

Comment: Nice, now people know exactly where you are blocked right now. I'm afraid the way you try to authenticate the client isn't going to work with AD. The way it should be handled is described [by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AuthenticationAndAuthorizationGuide/AuthenticationAndAuthorizationGuide.pdf), look for Kerberos and you'll see it is much more complicated. Have you tried to delegate auth challenge as described at the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` documentation ?